# How to replace part of a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace, find, substring

Im trying to replace part of a String based on a certain phrase being present within it. Consider the string *"Hello my Dg6Us9k. I am alive."*.

I want to search for the phase "my" and remove 8 characters to the right, which removes the hash code. This gives the string *"Hello. I am alive."* How can i do this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hello my Dg6Us9k. I am alive";
    String newString=s.replaceFirst("\\smy\\s\\w{7}", "");
    System.out.println(newString);
}
```

O/P :
`Hello. I am alive`

Comment: The w before brackets means it will search a word? 7 is maximum length or required length?

Comment: @Kahler - exact 7. w can match `a-zA-Z_`

Comment: This works pretty well, thanks for the suggestion! However it does need to be passed to a string first before it displays the amended string.

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this through `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("\\bmy.{8}", "");
```

Add `\\b` if necessary. `\\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. `.{8}` matches exactly the following 8 characters.

To remove also the space before `my`

```
System.out.println("Hello my Dg6Us9k. I am alive.".replaceAll("\\smy.{8}", ""));
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'add \\b if necessary'? What does it do?

Comment: @TheLostMind edited according to his expexted output but he says I want to search for the phase "my" and remove 8 characters to the right`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - ya.. but once I ran the program, his expected output differes from his *question* :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
String s = ("Hello my Dg6Us9k. I am alive");
s.replace(s.substring(s.indexOf("my"), s.indexOf("my")+11),"");
```

That is replacing the string starts at "my" and is 11 char long with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are immutable, so you cannot *change* the string. You have to create a new string. So, find the index *i* of "my". Then concatenate the substring before (0...*i*) and after (*i+8*...).

```
int i = s.indexOf("my");
if (i == -1) { /* no "my" in there! */ }
string ret = s.substring(0,i);
ret.concat(s.substring(i+2+8));
return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be flexible about the hash code length, use the folowing regexp:

```
String foo="Hello my Dg6Us9k. I am alive.";
String bar = foo.replaceFirst("\\smy.*?\\.", ".");
System.out.println(bar);
```