# How to remove known text from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a String like this:

```
https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/record-level-of-poorer-teens-aiming-for-a-degree-m6q6bfbq3
```

And I know that I want to remove this part:

```
https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace String with another in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Comment: Please show the expected result. I get the impression that some of the answers misunderstood the goal. Also please show what you tried yourself and explain how it failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace part of a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345198/how-to-replace-part-of-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use String::replace

```
String oldString = "https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/record-level-of-poorer-teens-aiming-for-a-degree-m6q6bfbq3";

String newString = oldString.replace ("https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

If we phrase the requirement as "remove everything after the last '/'", you can use [`lastIndexof`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) to find its position and then [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) to cut it:

```java
String result = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a regexp. It could be useful if you need to deal with the case where the input string doesn't start with the known string.

```
private static final Pattern RE = Pattern.compile("https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/(.*)");
```

...

```
Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(inputString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    return matcher.group(1);
} else {
    return inputString; // or null, or whatever
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can also use substring

String url=https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/record-level-of-poorer-teens-aiming-for-a-degree-m6q6bfbq3;
url.substring(36,url.length);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).